# trying to install paramiko for python3

Tags: python, python3, pip

I'm trying to install paramiko3 on Python3

```
pip3 install paramiko
```

However, I have this

```
Downloading/unpacking cryptography>=1.5 (from paramiko)
  Downloading cryptography-2.1.4.tar.gz (441kB): 441kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_andykw/cryptography/setup.py) egg_info for package cryptography
    error in cryptography setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version < '3'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in cryptography setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version < '3'
```

As you can see, it seems to be related to `cryptography`.

I tried to install the package alone and I have the same result

```
Downloading/unpacking cryptography
  Downloading cryptography-2.1.4.tar.gz (441kB): 441kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_andykw/cryptography/setup.py) egg_info for package cryptography
    error in cryptography setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version < '3'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in cryptography setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version < '3'
```

From the [doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography), it says that cryptography is supported in Python 2 and 3. Yet this marker thing is weird. I did not find anything on internet.

Any ideas?

---

update: my release version of ubuntu

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

This is what I have when I tried to install `paramiko` through `apt-get``

```
[andykw:/home/andykw]$ sudo apt install python3-paramiko
[sudo] password for andykw:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-paramiko
```

Comment: Dunno about the version on PyPI, but you can get an older, stable version (1.2.3 on Xenial) from the Ubuntu repos using `sudo apt install python3-cryptography`. As your Paramiko needs a newer version though, maybe also use the version from Ubuntu's repositories here instead (which also depends on `python3-crypto` and not `python3-cryptography` for some reason...): `sudo apt install python3-paramiko`.

Comment: hi @ByteCommander `sudo apt-get install python3-paramiko` does not install...

Comment: Would you care to explain why/what exactly happens when you try? Also, which Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: @ByteCommander for what's happening, everything is up there. I did not give more details because there are no additional details. For the ubuntu release, check my update.

Comment: I see why the `pip3 install` doesn't work in your question, but you didn't say anything about why `apt-get install` failed. However, as you added you're on 14.04, for that release only `python-paramiko` exists as an apt package, which is for Python 2... No idea then.

Comment: @ByteCommander the remaining update.

Comment: Is updating to a more recent version of Ubuntu which *does* have the package `python3-paramiko` (e.g. 16.04) an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After recreating a VM with `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`, I was able to install `paramiko` on python3.

Thanks for the help